# Getting JsonException:End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json

I've an API in php which sends the data in Json format and it wont require any request parameters. When I open that php file on browser, its working fine but when I accessing the same API on android it is returning this JsonException: End of input at character 0 of.

I've tried GET method too.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String contents ;
TextView sampleText;
String urlLink = "http://192.168.0.56/login/text.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sampleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    new DownloadContent().execute();
    sampleText.setText(contents);

   }

    class DownloadContent extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlLink);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                osw.write(json.toString());
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();


                int responceCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(responceCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(in));
                    contents = jsonObject.getString("1");

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        private String convertStreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

            reader.close();
            Log.i("test", sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();

        }

    }
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,"register_db");

if(!$conn) {
    die("connection error:" . $conn->connect_error) ;

  }
 $string = array('1' => 'testing');
echo json_encode($string);
?>
```

Comment: Check your URL, I think it have white space at starting point.

Comment: `getString()`method takes a `key` as an input parameter and returns you string the `value`corresponding to that key. You are not passing anything to it. Pass `"1"` instead of `""`.

Comment: No, nothing like that. Actually it is connecting to that link and getting null response @Shane

Comment: I didn't updated here sorry. But I've passed the key as "1" in the code and still throwing the same error. @PrerakSola

Comment: Try printing out your `jsonObject` in the logs. What do you get? Also, what does `convertStreamToString ` method do?

Comment: I tried to log the Json object but not got the output. While processing the Json object I'm getting exception. `convertStreamToString` which converts output stream data into string. @PrerakSola

Comment: If your API does not require any request parameters, there is no need of writing a `JSONObject` on `OutputStream`. In your `convertStreamToString` method, log the value of `sb.toString()` before returning it. What do you get in that?

Comment: Even I tried removing `JsonObject` on `OutputStream`, Still it didn't work. I logged `sb.toString` in `convertStreamToString`. I got the null value. @PrerakSola

Comment: It means, your API is not returning anything. Try to call the URL from a mobile browser to make sure your API is reachable from the test device.

Comment: Yea! I'm getting the response from mobile browser. @PrerakSola

Comment: Can you please post your complete class?

Comment: @PrerakSola posted complete class. Thanks!